# Dividir un string según X palabras

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de separar un texto en dos partes, una primera de al rededor 1000 caracteres y el resto, el problema es que esto me corta palabras ¿como puedo hacerlo para que separe el texto en las 50 primeras frases por ejempl?

Esto es lo que he probado:

```
echo substr($contenido, 0, 1000);
echo substr($contenido, 1001);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```php
echo substr($contenido, 0, strpos($contenido, ' ', 1000));
```

O tal como sugiere **@msalinas** en su comentario, relativo a codificación de caracteres multibyte, con esto:

```php
echo mb_substr($contenido, 0, mb_strpos($contenido, ' ', 1000));
```

**Explicación:**

- La sintaxis de substr es la siguiente a groso modo:

```php
substr($cadena, $inicio, $longitud)
```

que aplicado a esta solución seria:

```php
$cadena = $contenido
$inicio = 0 (principio de linea)
$longitud = strpos($contenido, ' ', 1000)
```

Lo importante en este caso es *cómo determinar la longitud correcta* para que **más o menos** sea de 1000 caracteres **sin partir ninguna palabra**. Por lo que aplicamos la [función `strpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php) la cual escribimos así:

```php
strpos($contenido, ' ', 1000)
```

**donde:**

- *$contenido* es la cadena de texto donde vamos a realizar la búsqueda
- `' '` es el caracter **espacio** que vamos a buscar
- `1000` es el offset (tambien llamado *desplazamiento*) que vamos a aplicar a esa búsqueda. Es decir, la cantidad de caracteres que vamos a despreciar antes de empezar la búsqueda, en este caso 1000.

Por lo tanto, nos va a devolver un valor igual o superior a 1001, coincidiendo con el primer espacio que encuentre a partir del caracter 1000, y eso evitará que partamos ninguna palabra.

Comment: Para no tener quebraderos de cabeza con esta solución mejor usar las funciones [mb_substr](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-substr.php) y [mb_strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strpos). Si las palabras tienen acentos, etc... puede dar resultados no esperados (lo digo porque me ha ocurrido en el pasado )

Comment: @msalinas Lo acabo de agregar a la respuesta, gracias por tu aporte :-)

Comment: Gracias a ti @masterguru que pones tantas "güenas" repuestas 

Comment: No se si son buenas, creo que me excedo en algunas, parece que haga respuestas  para dummies y no estoy seguro si lo estoy haciendo bien del todo a veces. Pero bueno, se me da bien enrollarme y me cuesta ser breve :-)  Aparte que tengo cierta práctica publicando y editando contenidos, por lo que me sale casi de forma natural.

Comment: Ya digo yo que lo haces genial! Además de aportar la solución aportas el por qué y eso ayuda a entenderlo bien y aprenderlo, con tu respuesta he entendido el funcionamiento y modificado para conseguir lo que quería finalmente. Millones de gracias @masterguru

Answer (score 0):

I think that manual responses should also be encouraged. This is my substr, I hope it helps you.

```
<?php

function salto($string, $size){
$i = 0;
$count = 0;
$newstring = '';
$var = 0;
$var1 = $size;

do {
        $aux = strlen($string) - $var;
        if ($size > $aux) {
                $var1 = $var + $aux;
        }
        for ($i = $var; $i < $var1; $i++) {
                $newstring .= $string[$i];
                $count++;
        }
        $var += $size;
        $var1 += $size;
        $newstring .= "<br>";
} while ($count < strlen($string));
return $newstring;
}

$string = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrsabcdefghijklmnñopqr1abcdefghijklmnñopqr2abcdefghijklmnñopqr3abcdefghijklmnñopqr4abcdefghijklmnñopqr5etc...";
$newstring = salto($string, 21);
echo  "<br>" . $newstring;
```

Output:

```
abcdefghijklmnñopqrs
abcdefghijklmnñopqr1
abcdefghijklmnñopqr2
abcdefghijklmnñopqr3
abcdefghijklmnñopqr4
abcdefghijklmnñopqr5
etc...
```

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Traduce tu respuesta.